# Numbers as column name in tibbles: problem when using select()

Tags: r, tibble

I am trying to select some column by name, and the names are numbers. This is the code:

```
df2 <- df1 %>% select(`Year`, all_of(append(list1, list2))) %>%
```

I get this error:

> Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist. x Locations 61927,
> 169014, 75671, 27059, 225963, etc. don't exist. i There are only 5312
> columns.

I think the error is due to column names being numbers. How do I solve it? (I want to keep the column name as numbers)

Comment: Can you share your data with `dput`?

Comment: unfortunately I cannot, what do you think the problem might be?

Comment: I gave an example, of what I think it is @randomwalker

Comment: If you can't share your actual data you can create a fake dataset which is similar to your actual data to make the question reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

We may use `any_of` with `paste` so that if there are numeric values as column names, it still work and if some of them are missing too, it would not throw an error

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    select(Year, any_of(paste(c(list1, list2))))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you insert a number in select it will use as position, buy you can use the number as characters.

### Example

```
library(dplyr)

df <-  tibble(`2020` = NA,`2021` = NA, "var" = NA)

df

# A tibble: 1 x 3
  `2020` `2021` var  
  <lgl>  <lgl>  <lgl>
1 NA     NA     NA
```

### Using number inside select

I will give an error, since there just 3 variables, and if you use 2020 will search the 2020th column.

```
df %>% 
  select(2020)
```

> Erro: Can't subset columns that don't exist. x Location 2020 doesn't
> exist. i There are only 3 columns.

### Using number as string inside select

```
df %>% 
  select("2020")

# A tibble: 1 x 1
  `2020`
  <lgl> 
1 NA
```

Comment: OK so how do transform the list of numbers in strings?

Comment: You can create a vector with them, and use `as.character`

Answer (score 0):

You can clean the column names using the janitor package.

```
df1 <- janitor::clean_names(df1)
```